# Set Active Direcory Pasword via PHP and LDAPS

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Okay I am stumped.

I am trying to write some PHP code to create a user in active directory with a password.

The PHP will run an  Ubuntu server if it makes any difference talking to a Server 2008r2 Windows Domain Controller.

I can create the user no problems using PHP but I can not set the password. I have tried what feels like every possible code on the internet but it just will not work.

I believe that I have to create the user and then modify the password after. As a result I have the following code.

```
$domadlogin =  'domainadminusername';
    $domadpw =  'a2b3c4d5e';
    $domctrl = 'ldaps://DCIPADDRESS';

    $ldapServer = $domctrl;
    $ldapBase =  'OU=Users,DC=example,DC=co,DC=uk';
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer);
    if (!$ds) {die('Cannot Connect to LDAP server');}
    $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ds,$domadlogin,$domadpw);
    if (!$ldapBind) {die('Cannot Bind to LDAP server');}
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $dn_user='CN=Test User,OU=New Users,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=co,DC=uk';;

    $newPassword =  "1.Password!";
    $newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
    $len = strlen($newPassword);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
    $newPassw .= "{$newPassword{$i}}\000";
    }
    $newPassword = base64_encode($newPassw);
    $userdata['unicodePwd'] = $newPassword;
    $result = ldap_modify($ds, $dn_user, $userdata);
        if ($result) echo "User modified!" ;
    else echo "There was a problem!";

    ldap_unbind($ds);
```

I know that LDAPS is working as this works

```
ldapsearch -x -d 2 -LLL -H ldaps://DCIPADDRESS -b 'OU=Users,DC=example,DC=co,DC=uk' -D 'domainadminusername' -W '(sAMAccountName=username)'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'am not a PHP writer here some guidelines from one of a closed question I answered :

Using PHP, you can change or create a user with the good password an AD user password using LDAP with a simple bind on an SSL connexion.

For this you need to install a certificate on you AD server. The simple way (not the more attractive) is to install Microsoft Certificate Server on your domain (Enterprise installation [see Configuring Microsoft Active Directory for SSL Access](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Configuring_Microsoft_Active_Directory_for_SSL_Access)) and then to reboot your domain controler. You can also generate a certificate with OpenSSL and install it on the computer (see [How to enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051/en-us)).

Here is a sample of an LDIF File that allow to create a user with his password on an SSL connexion, you will find the way I generate the base 64 string for the password :

```
# Imported with :
# ldifde -i -t 636 -f .\Annuaire3.ldf
# Password generated by ("" must be encoded inside):
# stringconverter.exe \"test.2011\" /unicode /encode
# Connexion then tested with :
# runas /user:jdupont cmd.exe (password is test.2011)

dn: cn=Jean Dupont,OU=MonOU,DC=societe0,DC=fr
changetype: add
objectClass: user
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Jean Dupont
givenName: Jean
sn: Dupont
mail: jean.Dupont@societe.fr
telephoneNumber: 9999
userAccountControl: 544
sAMaccountName: jdupont
userPrincipalName: jdupont@societe.fr
unicodePwd:: IgB0AGUAcwB0AC4AMgAwADEAMQAiAA==
```